# Can I recover notes from before I factory reset my phone?

Tags: applications, root-access, data-recovery, notes

I have a Poco X3 NFC and did a factory reset just yesterday, but apparently lost a very important password and I can't seem to get it any other way. It was stored as a note from the "notes" app by Xiaomi and I don't even know which type of file to look for or if there's any software for that task.

Thanks in advance

Comment: no data can be recovered from phone. that's the main purpose of factory reset. check mi cloud for backup

Answer (score 0):

If your password was in a .txt file, maybe you can root your device and use third party software, the only downside is you'll have to pay a lot only to begin with if it even finds the file, maybe the software will let you view the password if it finds it,therefore it will be most likely that if it wasn't in a text format, no software can restore the password data unless it was a screenshot that was deleted. I'm sure you may have found a way, if not, the password is long gone. The only fix is if you written it somewhere safe beforehand or have it somewhere deep in your brain. I highly recommend you use a password manager that you can link to your Google account.